# Export Data from Postgres To ElasticSearch Using Logstash Gives LoadError: no such file to load -- pg

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-jdbc

I am trying to export data from Postgres To ElasticSearch Using Logstash.

Here is my conf file, which is at path "**/etc/logstash/conf.d**"

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "postgresql://localhost:5432/panzura"
        jdbc_user => "panzura"
    jdbc_password => "*******"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/jdbc-drivers/postgresql-42.2.9.jar"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from file"
    }
}

filter { }


output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "files"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        hosts => "https://vzfnrf9q3fagdht05b:xw32qdcnr4w2zgss@es.vizion.ai:443"
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to run logstash using command:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/pg-to-elastic.conf
```

But I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] 2019-12-28 14:50:38.339 [[main]<jdbc] jdbc - Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"LoadError: no such file to load -- pg"}
[ERROR] 2019-12-28 14:50:38.361 [[main]<jdbc] javapipeline - A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_user=>"panzura", jdbc_validate_connection=>true, jdbc_password=><password>, statement=>"SELECT * from file", jdbc_driver_library=>"/etc/logstash/jdbc-drivers/postgresql-42.2.9.jar", jdbc_connection_string=>"postgresql://localhost:5432/panzura", id=>"07d4c82d79b5f028b0563465cafb72e0dfbc5833c51be9658f8dd516f69a0fbf", jdbc_driver_class=>"org.postgresql.Driver", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_d31ea3e3-207b-41c3-9593-f2139bdb2b55", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, plugin_timezone=>"utc", last_run_metadata_path=>"/home/alcanzar/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true, use_prepared_statements=>false>
  Error: LoadError: no such file to load -- pg
  Exception: Sequel::AdapterNotFound
  Stack: org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:987:in `require'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.27.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:6:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:987:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1015:in `require_relative'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.27.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgresql.rb:1:in `<main>'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:987:in `require'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.27.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:88:in `load_adapter'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.27.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:17:in `adapter_class'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.27.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:36:in `connect'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.27.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:121:in `connect'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.19/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:120:in `block in jdbc_connect'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1425:in `loop'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.19/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:117:in `jdbc_connect'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.19/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:184:in `open_jdbc_connection'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.19/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:243:in `execute_statement'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.19/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:309:in `execute_query'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.19/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:322:in `inputworker'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:314:in `block in start_input'
...
...
```

If we focus on first line, it says :

```
Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"LoadError: no such file to load -- pg"}
```

I am unable to solve this.

Comment: the input filter for `jdbc` seems correct in your post unless one of those values is missing in those mentioned paths. The reason I say is because this error info from the stack you put up there `Exception: Sequel::AdapterNotFound`  Have you connected to Postgres using normal means? like `pgAdmin` etc

Comment: @JBone, I am using that same database with other application, it is working fine, and I am able to connect to it, with given credentials. I can connect to using Node App as well as DBeaver Application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!
I was trying to find a solution for two days. I simply solved it by giving all users Read&Write permission (I'm using Mac OS) to the pipeline.conf file, and instead of writing: 
"Users/user/Desktop/postgresql-42.2.9.jar", you write: "~/Desktop/postgresql-42.2.9.jar"